# Angularjs - ng-disabled with angular.isDefined doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to enable/disable the radio button based on the value from backend when I open kendo window. I used `ng-disabled` with `angular.isDefined` and `angular.isUndefined` in the HTML but it is not working. Here is my code below.
As per below backend data this progressive radio button should be disabled.

```
<div class="col-md-6 zero-left-padding ligther" style="margin-left:-107px;">
    <label for="progressive">
        <input type="radio" id="progressive" name="version" 
                ng-model="adhocTranscode.version" ng-value="24" 
                ng-disabled="{{angular.isUndefined(jobDetails.aes_data.instance_type_urlmap.nonlinear-progressive) &&                                     angular.isDefined(jobDetails.aes_data.instance_type_urlmap.broadcast) }}"/>
        <span style="font-weight:lighter;">Progressive &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
    </label>
```

Backend JSON object:

```
"aes_data" : {
     "instance_type_urlmap" : {
      "broadcast" : "file://int/edam/mbr/broadcast/0067/0067031_CQ-0101_I.MXF"
    }
```

Comment: Can you put more about your code? Anyway I can help with that: you can use expressions `{{ }}` if it exists on scope.

Comment: Anyway I would put your expression inside a controller method. And you can easily debug from that, for example using `console.log()` to see what you are returning from backend. Can be happining several errors there.

Comment: Have you thought about the `-` in your ng-disabled expression? It's most likely being interpreted as a minus sign. I

Answer (score 0):

One way is to change it to following code:

```
 <input type="radio" id="progressive" name="version" 
                ng-model="adhocTranscode.version" ng-value="24" 
                ng-disabled="jobDetails.aes_data.instance_type_urlmap.nonlinear-progressive === undefined &&                                     jobDetails.aes_data.instance_type_urlmap.broadcast !== undefined }}"/>
```

Notice that the **angular.isUndefined** was replaced with ***=== undefined*** and **angular.isDefined** was replaced by ***!== undefined***.

The issue might be that angular is undefined in the html context. If one want to use the angular.isDefined or angular.isUndefined then assign the result to a variable and then use variable in html.

js:

```
var vm = this;
vm.result = angular.isDefined(someVariable);//false
vm.result2 = angular.isUndefined(someVariable);//true
```

html:

```
<input ng-disable="vm.result"></input><!--Enabled-->
<input ng-disable="vm.result2></input><!--Disabled-->
```

[Angularjs isDefined API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.isDefined)